# logarithm inequality solve

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> Solve the following inequality:
>   $x^{2\log_56}-3\cdot6^{\log_5x}+42\le0$

do you have any ideas on how to run this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^{2\log_56}-3\cdot6^{\log_5x}+42\le0$$

The trick is that we have $$x^{\log_56}= 6^{\log_5x}$$

thus the equation is changed to $$y^2-3y+42\le 0$$

The above inequality doesn not have any real  solution because it is always positive.

Comment: Thanks! a few hours pats tasks with logarithmic inequalities and I still can't do some without help